# Combining information from multiple distributions

Tags: distributions

I have 13 classes. For each class, I have a different distribution: e.g.

[image]

For each distribution, the y-axis indicates the probability and the x-axis indicates a count value.

Given some input data, I want to map it to a count value. I have calculated the probabilities that the input falls into each class (i.e. a 1 x 13 vector). But now, how can I combine information from all 13 distributions to obtain a single count value? I thought about two ways:

1. Compute the weighted sum of the modes for each distribution
2. Compute the weighted sum of each distribution to get a new distribution, and find the mode of this new distribution

However, I could not find any academic justifications or formal math theories to support my intuitions. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Are my intuitions entirely wrong? I checked out mixture distributions and linear polling, but they do not quite seem to be what I am looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the input data, $c \in \{1, \dots, 13\}$ be the class, and $n$ be the count. What you're  after is $p(n \mid x)$, the conditional distribution over count, given the input data (or some statistic that summarizes this distribution). Following the definition of marginal probability, this is obtained by summing $p(n,c \mid x)$ (the joint distribution of count and class, given the input data) over all possible classes:

$$p(n \mid x) = \sum_{c=1}^{13} p(n,c \mid x)$$

Following the definition of conditional probability, $p(n,c \mid x)$ can factorized as $p(n \mid c,x) p(c \mid x)$. If the count depends directly only on the class (i.e. count and input are conditionally independent, given class), then $p(n \mid c,x) = p(n \mid c)$ and therefore $p(n,c \mid x) = p(n \mid c) p(c \mid x)$. Plugging this in:

$$ p(n \mid x) = \sum_{c=1}^{13} p(n \mid c) p(c \mid x)$$

This can be seen as a sum of the count distributions for each class, weighted by the probabilities that the input is a member of each class. This corresponds to the second approach you mentioned. Keep in mind that this requires the conditional independence assumption I mentioned above (i.e. the input doesn't carry any additional information about the count, beyond that carried by its class). If you want, you can then find a statistic that summarizes this distribution (e.g. the mean or mode).

Comment: Great and clear explanation - upvoted! Out of curiosity, do you know if the first method can be justified mathematically as well?

Comment: @umopapisdn You could think of method 2 as computing $p(n \mid x)$ the same as method 1, but with each class conditional count distribution approximated as a delta function located at the mode. Then, taking the mean as the final summary statistic. This may well be a poor approximation, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I think I get it, thank you.

Comment: @umopapisdn correction to my earlier comment: "you could think of method 2 as computing $p(n \mid x)$ the same as method 1...." should read "you could think of method 1 as computing $p(n \mid x)$ the same as method 2..."

Comment: I guessed what you meant :) Thanks!